# Cutting a hole straight through an object using geometry nodes without using the mesh boolean node

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

Cutting a hole straight through an object using geometry nodes without using the mesh boolean node.

Is it possible to cut a hole straight through an object using just geometry nodes and **not use the mesh boolean node and another object** (I'm trying to avoid the mesh boolean node it sometimes adds artifacts and at times can be slow).

I start off with this:

[image: img1]

But when I try and extrude / cut a hole all the way through it just extends the faces below the object.

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you "just" want to make a hole in a cylinder, you can use this node setup:

[image]

or if the "object" has just a thickness:

[image]